# how to setup a windows 10 dual boot on both existing systems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a computer with 2 drives in it, one with windows 10, the other ubuntu 18.04 LTS, how i have used the system in the past was to swap the plugs on the drives to boot either into windows or into ubuntu, Obviously this is a labourious process, the issue is i cannot re-install either (programs and setups issues) but i would like to find out how to do a dual boot? if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

i have tried searching for a solution on my own, and all i can find is how to do it as a clean install, i would really like to avoid this.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Only use Windows to shrink the NTFS & immediately reboot to run chkdsk & turn off Windows fast start up.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I've seen lots of tutorials about setting up a computer with one disk to boot into Windows or Ubuntu by using a boot manager.  I would assume something like that would be able to do the same for different disks and not different partitions. Are you able to plug both disks in simultaneously?

Comment: Both discs are plugged in simultaneously, found its easier to switch between them in the BIOS (which answers the UEFI vs BIOS question, BIOS of course). The boot loader is Grub and what i was asking was, how would i go about editing grub to make my system a dual boot system, when one of the drives already has the windows boot loader on it.

Comment: Dual Boot advice:

I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Boot Ubuntu drive, in Treminal run "sudo update-grub". This should add your Windows to the grub menu.